# wordcount with the text file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to analyze a text file by Using Hadoop MapReduce.

a CVS file was easier to analyze because it can distinguish between columns with ','

But the text file can not be distinguished like a CVS file.

This is a text file format.

`2015-8-02`

`error2014 blahblahblahblah`

`2015-8-02`

`blahblahbalh error2014`

I want an output as

```
date      contents  sum of errors

2015-8-02  error2014  2
```

I would like to analyze in this way. What should I do with the MapReduce program.

Comment: Do you have the text file with the date and error line in different lines?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the text file in the following format :

2015-8-02

error2014 blahblahblahblah

2015-8-02

blahblahbalh error2014

---

You could use [NLineInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.0.3-alpha/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/NLineInputFormat.html).

With `NLineInputFormat` functionality, you can specify exactly how many lines should go to a mapper.

In your case you can use to input 2 lines per mapper.

**EDIT**:

Here is an example for using NLineInputFormat:

**Mapper Class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class MapperNLine extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(key, value);
    }

}
```

**Driver class:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.out
                  .printf("Two parameters are required for DriverNLineInputFormat- <input dir> <output dir>\n");
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = new Job(getConf());
        job.setJobName("NLineInputFormat example");
        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(NLineInputFormat.class);
        NLineInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.getConfiguration().setInt("mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 2);

        LazyOutputFormat.setOutputFormatClass(job, TextOutputFormat.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setMapperClass(MapperNLine.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new Driver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

Then you can extract the date and error from the lines. After extracting the date and error you can then pass them as a composite key or as concatenated string as a key and an IntWritable as value like a WordCount example and then do a basic add in the reducer class agin similar to the WordCount example.

I hope I was able to answer your question.

Comment: thanks for a great answer!
but im a really beginner..

i want to extract two things.
1) date  2) errors

but the textfile's format is

2015-07-31
asdfsadfsadf
asdfsadfsadfasdf
'error'  asdfsadfsadf
asdfasdfdsaf asdffds

it is 5lines  
then do i have to (mapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap", 5)?
and in mapper class..
what shoud i do?
i want to extract date and errors

please help me again